# How do I make an image act as a video overlay?

Tags: css, html

I want an image to lay on top of a video in HTML 5. Currently I just force the image into place using CSS positioning, but I cant figure out how to get it to stay in place if the page gets to small or changes significantly.

How do I tie the image and the video together?

Here is the code

```
<style>
<!--
.container{
    position: relative;
}
.vidContainer faceVideo{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
}
.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 193px;
    left: 42px;
    z-index: 1;
}
-->
</style>
...
<div class="container">
    <div class="vidContainer">
        <video id="faceVideo" autoplay="autoplay" width="500px"
    height="375px" style="border-style: solid; border-color: black; border-width: medium;"></video>
        <div class="overlay"><img alt="Logo" src="Frame.png" style="height: 375px; width: 500px;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please show your code/what you've tried

Comment: You could wrap the video in a div and position the image relative to the video div

Comment: How would I position the image relative to the vid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If for some reason [Nick's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31928250/361684) doesn't work for you, here's an alternative approach:

Put the image and the video in a relatively positioned parent element.  Use `position: absolute` on the image and have it fill the parent element.

Answer (score 2):

Make it a [poster url](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video).

```
<video poster="your-url.png" />
```

Comment: But I want the overlay to be there while the video is streaming, doesn't the poster url stop displaying when the video starts playing?

Comment: @Parttimereaper why do you want to do something like that?

Comment: I am using it as a positioning guide on the video stream